# golang time.Now().Unix() discrepancy between documentation and implementation?

Tags: go, time

https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Unix

states that the signature of this function is

```
func Unix(sec int64, nsec int64) Time
```

meaning, it returns a `Time` object.

But the following program aborts with the error message:

> 14: cannot use now.Unix() (type int64) as type time.Time in assignment`

```
func main() {
    var now time.Time
    now = time.Now()
    fmt.Println(now)

    var secs time.Time
    secs = now.Unix()
    fmt.Println(secs)
}
```

The following version of the program produces output

```
func main() {
    var now time.Time
    now = time.Now()
    fmt.Println(now)

    // var secs time.Time
    secs := now.Unix()
    fmt.Println(secs)
}
```

`2016-04-12 18:20:22.566965512 -0400 EDT`

`1460499622`

Is this just a matter of error in documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs are correct, you're looking at the wrong version of `Unix`. The method you're using is this; https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Unix it takes no arguments, is called on a time object and returns the unix time as an `int64`. The version you're referencing takes two arguments, both int64's, the seconds and nanoseconds? (not positive that's what the nseconds stands for) which represent a time in unix format and it returns a `time.Time`

So to extend your second example;

```
func main() {
    var now time.Time
    now = time.Now()
    fmt.Println(now)

    // var secs time.Time
    secs := now.Unix()
    fmt.Println(secs)
    t := time.Unix(secs, 0) // get a time from the seconds value which is a unix time
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Here's the above in play with one other line added to print the type of `secs`. https://play.golang.org/p/KksPPbQ1Jy

Comment: `nsec` in the `time.Unix` function is nanoseconds. You can specify the timestamp in seconds, nanoseconds, or a combination of the two.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! These functions are in a sense inverses of each other. seconds <-->Time object converters.